# Find and Replace a certain word with two options

Tags: html, regex, notepad++

So I thought of using notepad++ to be more efficient with something I'm working on, I'm hoping that what I want is possible with Notepad++ or through any other method.

Is it possible to find replace let's say "USA" with "United Kingdom" and "united-kingdom" and vice-versa.

I'm working with urls and it's a pain to rinse and repeat manually replacing "united-kingdom" with USA or "United Kingdom" to "united-kingdom"

if this isn't possible at all then thank you for your time.

Can't show code as it is confidential. Thanks.

Best I can do is:

Case 1:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book
<a href="http://www.sample.com/book/lorem-ipsum/">Lorem Ipsum</a>
```

to:

```
The Dominican Republic is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry
The Dominican Republic has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book
<a href="http://www.sample.com/book/the-dominican-republic/">The Dominican Republic</a>
```

Case 2:

```
USA is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry
USA has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book
<a href="http://www.sample.com/book/lorem-ipsum/">Lorem Ipsum</a>
```

to:

```
The Dominican Republic is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry
The Dominican Republic has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book
<a href="http://www.sample.com/book/the-dominican-republic/">The Dominican Republic</a>
```

edit: if you read the conversations I've had with the people who answered,it's sort of answered by recording a macro but I guess I am either looking for a very specific not yet made macro or I'll just have to "search and replace manually"

edit 2: added 2 cases which regularly encounter and to clarify even more. Working with HTML which contains paragraphs of text with links here and there which contain the words I need replacing. Showed two instances because sometimes I need to replace a single word with two or more words which have two distinct formats: the URL form which should replace USA to 'united-kingdom' and USA to "United Kingdom". Really new with Regex, and the more I read about it, I think what I want is possible through one expression.

Though I don't know if it's possible through code to detect if the word/s to be replaced is more than one. Like USA, the expression knows that it's only one word, but if the words to be replaced is United Kingdom, the expression knows that two words need to be replaced.

TL;DR: Is it possible with REGEX to search and replace a word and that same word within a url and replace them with a different string of words formatted properly?

Maybe point me to references?

I understand my problem is complicated and if mod/s or anyone else needs to shut this down, I completely understand.

Comment: How would the tool know where to insert what ? Where to replace with "United Kingdom" and where to replace with "united-kingdom". Simply put, this is not possible.

Comment: Thought so. Could there be a plugin where it can identify a url string and search for specific strings such as "united-kingdom"?

or

a plugin to have a second search field to do the other one? Since notepad++ can already search for match case only.

Comment: There is an even better option - **Find & Replace "in selection"**. You can simply manually drag & select the section you want to search from > Find & Replace > check the "in selection" checkbox there.

Answer (score 0):

That's what macros are for.

[image: macro toolbar]

Start recording with the red button, replace one occurrence, stop the macro and then run it til EoF with the 4th button.

e: Remember to save it after recording it so you can save the two you need.

e2: on further clarification, what you'd record are two replacements, one for `United Kingdom` and another for `united-kingdom`, and *then* stop the macro.

Comment: Hmm,would that be possible as a generic macro?Since I'll be repeating the same process but with different sets of words to search and replace.

Comment: Other than opening and editing the file where macros are stored, i don't think it can be done.

Comment: Yeah, just discovered that. Well thanks for your input anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got what you want here https://regex101.com/r/wbrd5Z/2

First you have to copy in the end of your file the strings you want to replace with, my case I did `/united-kingdom/ /USA/`

Then you use a conditional regex to find /USA/ or /United Kingdom/

If find `/USA/` its replacing with `/united-kingdom/` if it finds `/United Kingdom/` it's replacing with `/USA/`

And for replace you use a \1 for getting what is got for the first group, search for "regex group".

with notepad++ you will open your find and replace and mark a regex checkbox. Then the syntax there may be a little different.

Let me know if you have any doubt.

Comment: I added a relatively long edit to my main post with a TL;DR on the end.

Comment: @Mandirigma what I did here is not what you want?